# What is the meaning of "be places"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

Recently I saw the sentence "Sometimes I just am places". What does it mean?

Actually, it was used when one of the characters in the movie asked his friend "why are you here?", and his friend answered "Beats me. Sometimes I just am places."

Comment: The implied rest of this sentence is, "...for no particular reason," since it's responding to a "why...?" question. A more common way of expressing the same idea is, "I have to be *somewhere*." The speaker either has no real reason for being in that place, or they are trying to hide their reasons from the other person.

Comment: We see something similar with "I have places I need to be."

Comment: Thank you @CanadianYankee and DjinTonic.    

How can the word " places " be used like that?

Isn't it a noun?

Comment: As a native speaker "be places" is just pure nonsense.

Comment: To be clear, it's a unique and spontaneous construction and understood as such. Although it would seem to introduce grammatical paradoxes, it really just parallels the construction of "Why are you here?"

Comment: Good dialog usually matches how real people speak. See comments on this very site from  the wisest of our community with common language: kinda, sorta, probly. They're being friendly and natural. Scripts that sound like school books make for horrid films.

Comment: @AlanA This native speaker finds it anything but nonsense. It is an unusual, possibly unique, construction and is obviously humorous in intent but it's perfectly consistent with the more standard sentence "I have places I need to be" which is used quite regularly to say that the speaker is busy and has commitments. It can be regarded as a shortening of "Sometimes I am just in places for no good reason" but, personally, I'm very happy with the shortened version, particularly as a humorous retort.

Comment: @BoldBen to clarify my issue is with "I just am places", not to "be places" as I wrote in my comment. The original "just am places" to me is an incomplete sentence and as such, to me doesn't make any sense. If it was said to me in conversation I would not understand. In my opinion it's like "my bad". My bad what? I do of course appreciate that the evolution of language is in the hands of those who use it but are we too busy or is life too hectic to complete a sentence?

Comment: There's an elided "in", it means "I am just in places" or "I am just someplace". As @AndyBonner said, it works as a parallel to the question.

Comment: It's kind of like the Bill & Ted "way!" as the opposite of "no way!".

Comment: @AlanA I see "Sometimes I just am places" also as being similar to "I am here" which, again, is perfectly standard. As I said I accept that "Sometimes I just am places" is unusual if not unique and is used for comic effect but that doesn't mean that it's invalid, it's more like a coined phrase.